# Low cost 1A-5V h-bridge ( MOSFET or BJT)

Tags: h-bridge

I like to build 8 dual direction PWM dc motor drive for dc motor with around 5V and 1A max current like shown below, and control it by Arduino with shift-register IC like 74HC595 :
[image]

So I googled and found h-bridge for this usage like L293D :
[image]

And also found some module [like TB6612FNG dc motor driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPPTRj0KWbg), but I like to reduce the cost below the cost of this module.

So I have seen [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162079/low-cost-h-bridge-circuit-for-pwm) question and I like to build the h-bridge drive for these 8 dc motor by myself like this:

[image]

In my opinion the Darlington transistors like [TIP series](https://www.electricalelibrary.com/en/2017/11/02/h-bridge/) are good but the cost for 4 of them is similar to TB6612FNG module and in this condition I prefer to use like [this](https://easyeda.com/waltercarvajalc/line-following-1) (connection to Arduino and add module ...).

But I'd like to know other's suggestion about minimum cost BJT ic in market (like [BC161](https://www.matiot.com/bc161-pnp-transistor-to-39-1a) PNP Transistor TO-39 1A) with around 1A max steady current-5v output for this goal.

**Update:**

I found [this](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/H-Bridge/H-Bridge-1) site and there is some good design like h bridge with [BD140 (1.5 max)](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=bd140%20h%20bridge&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5-4fI9tHqAhWJzKQKHYvBDGkQsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1527&bih=815) and [BC327 ( with max 800mA current )](https://waimeaelectronics.weebly.com/h-bridge.html)

Comment: No... Darlingtons are *truly horrible* to the point of being effectively unusable at five volts.  You want an FET solution.  The TB6612FNG is nice because it's documented, though importers seem to make modules for about the cost of bare chips.  There are other parts found in toys which are clearly cheap but not something you can easily learn about or buy loose.  Sourcing questions are, however, off-topic here.

Comment: You seem to miss the *fine-print* on data sheets. At 1A, the L293 will just burn up. While BC161 data sheet gives a 1A spec doesn't mean it will work for your application. It will consume about one volt of your 5V supply (an NPN in the H-bridge will consume almost another 1V). As Chris suggests, MOSfets having 0.1 ohm (or less) Rds-ON would be right. These MOSfets might be rated for 5A max current.

Comment: What does the triangle of motors picture bring to the party?

Comment: I have been using L293D and L298N modules and found them OK. Next time I might try TB6612FNG or BTS7960B. From time to time I don't use modules but DIY/assemble using protoboard, but it is very time consuming and not reliable.

Comment: Use 5V (logic level) MOSFETs with suitable low Rdson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a great heatsink choose 1A otherwise consider an H bridge rated for 2A.

Rohm is possibly the best source for H bridge motor drivers. From their catalog, I selected

BD6212FP  which is well-stocked at [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/BD6212FP-E2/BD6212FP-E2CT-ND/1739150?WT.z_cid=ref_netcomponents_dkc_buynow&utm_source=netcomponents&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_campaign=buynow) $2.38 (10)  You still need a PCB and heatsink copper pour of 1sq" per W around each IC.

[image]

I can't imagine a better choice for this project.  Read the datasheets thoroughly and follow the [training module](https://www.digikey.com/en/ptm/r/rohm-semiconductor/h-bridge-drivers-for-dc-brush-motors?pn_sku=BD6212FP-E2CT-ND&part_id=1739150).